# How to increase the number of doc links for assets in W2OS Governance Registry 5.3.0?

Tags: wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

All I seem to find, within the W2OS Governance registry documentation, is how to increase the number of columns for doc links for assets via the use of the RXT file. I would like to know if it is possible to increase the number of rows, in order to add more document links for assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the RXT file to have an unbounded table. There you can add multiple doc links without limiting to three. For detailed information, please refer "[The maxoccurs Element](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Governance+Artifacts+Configuration+Model+Elements#GovernanceArtifactsConfigurationModelElements-ThemaxoccursElement)" section in the product documentation.